# observable to return many json objects from server will contain all at once or iterate through?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, django, angular

I'm using angular 4 and typescript

I have created an api endpoint that will return a array of json objects. My question refers to capturing the json inside a variable designed to hold an array of javascript objects. Will the observable return a list of json objects to where I can just set the variable in my typescript code to that array? And if so how.

Or do I have to iterate through the list of json objects and append them to the array variable?

Notice no code, as I am confused as to when I use interaces, when I use constructors and the alike. I would like to see how this is done. I am still learning

Comment: first of all, you are using wrong tag here for your question.
Angular2/4 is tagged as Angular and Angular1 is tagged as AngularJS. I also did not know so there is no shame in it.

Comment: oops yep mistake

Comment: If your api returns a json array you can simple assign the response to the new array `let myArray = response` inside of you promise response, And handle myArray as an array

Comment: Thanks @DarwinMedina learning new lanuages  software concepts is fun but these tiny details that make everything work drive me nuts. Now do I need to set the variable thats holding an array to a type with an interface or will that be infered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getData(): Observable<Array<any>> {
return this.http.get("http://apiurl")
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Set Observable type to `Array<any>`,
you can replace any with your datatype.

Iterate over an array using

```
let list = [{"name": "john"}, {"name": "doe"}];

for (let i in list) {
   console.log(i); // indexes will be printed
}

for (let i of list) {
   console.log(i); // Actual values will be printed
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this observable will it return an array of josn objects or will it just return one json object at a time the API is set to return an array

Comment: Then it will return an array of objects.

Comment: @amazingCarrotSoup It will return array of objects at a time. You can then iterate through that array. I've updated the answer. Please check. Vote up if you think it helped you somehow. Thanks :)

Comment: @WasifKhan You are right.
Now in component you can use it like
getData() {

    this.service.getData().subscribe((dataArray: Array<any>) => {

            // iterate over dataArray here
        }

    );

}

Answer (score 0):

Service :

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`yourUrl`)
  .map(r => r.json());
}
```

Component :

```
yourFunction() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
        data => {
            // If your API returns an Array, then data is an array.
            // If it returns one line, then it's an object.
        }
    );
}
```